# csv_writer.writerow(line) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python-3.x

```
import csv

with open('dataDusta.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    with open('new_dataDusta.csv','w') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter = ",")

    for line in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your operations on `new_file` must be within the `with open(`... that you opened it with.  This includes using `csv_writer`, which is itself using `new_file`.